# Serialising XML from C# object that links to there objects

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a container class set up like this

```
[XmlRoot("Root")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(class1))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(class2))]
public class Root
{
    public string id {get;set;}
    public class1 Class1 {get;set;}
    public List<class2> Classes2 {get;set;}
}

[XmlType("class1")]
public class1 
{
    public string foo {get;set;}
    public int bar {get;set;}
}

[XmlType("class2")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(class3)]
{
    public double fred {get;set;}
    public bool mode {get;set;}
    public class3 Class3 {get;set;}
}

[XmlType("class3")]
{
    public int singular {get;set;}
}
```

(the actual names aren't that important, the point is that from the root, the others stem).

When I try and serialise to a file using XmlSerializer, I am getting the root but not the offshoots.

My XmlSerializer looks like this

```
 try
        {
            bgWorker.DoWork += (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) =>
            {
                var jobr = TechApp2.Singleton.DBManager.GetSingleObject<Root>("id", id);
                var emptyNs = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });
                var filename = Path.Combine(TechApp2.Singleton.ContentDirectory, typeof(Root).ToString() + "-" + id + ".xml");
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
                serializer.Serialize(File.Create(filename), jobr, emptyNs);
            };
            bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            bgWorker.CancelAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Exception thrown - {0}:{1}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
        }
```

Nothing earth shattering.

If I look at the jobr object in the debugger, the children from root are there and observable, but the object serialised is only the bare bones of root.

Something is not right, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 0):

the [XmlInclude] attribute is hinting XmlSerializer about inherited members of the base class, you don't need to use it if no inheritance is happening.

Collections are automatically serialized, you can use [XmlArray] attribute to rename the outer element.

Use the [XmlArrayItem] to rename the inner elements.